# R: two seemingly identical datasets but one works, one does not?

Tags: r, plyr, vegan

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31). Packages used are vegan, plyr, and bbmle.

I have two very large datasets. Let's call them `df1` and `df2`. Each looks like this:

```
 Taxon          Sam1001    Sam1002
 Bacteria01     0.25       0
 Bacteria02     0.11       0.34
```

The "good" dataset is `df1`. It has 1885 obs of 3013 variables. `df2` has 1674 obs of 2377 variables. When loaded, it also comes up with a warning:

```
See spec(...) for full column specifications.
Warning: 55 parsing failures.
row           col               expected  actual
1062 SAMN032937893 no trailing characters .12E-07
1062 SAMN032936513 no trailing characters .12E-07
1062 SAMN032936373 no trailing characters .12E-07
1062 SAMN032936273 no trailing characters .12E-07
1062 SAMN032937943 no trailing characters .12E-07
.... ............. ...................... .......
See problems(...) for more details.
```

I remove row 1062 since that seems to be an issue. I then run the following code:

```
df[df==0] <- NA
df2[df2==NA_integer_] <- NA #because NA_integer appears in the dataset df2
dfFreq <- apply(df, 2, count)
dfNARemoved <- lapply(dfFreq, function(x) transform(x[-nrow(x),]))
dfFreqxRemoved <- lapply(dfNARemoved, function(x) { x["x"] <- NULL; x 
}) #removing useless x column
dfSum <- lapply(dfFreqxRemoved, function(x) sum(x))
```

`df1` generates a list like so:

```
List of 3013
$ X1                  : int 1884
$ SAMN03073712        : int 191
$ SAMN03852278        : int 1
$ SAMN02142445        : int 100
$ SAMN03852340        : int 1
$ SAMEA2241190        : int 108
```

Etc. However, `df2` generates a list like this:

```
List of 38669
$ : num 1
$ : num 1
$ : num 1
$ : num 1
```

Edit: My overall goal is to take a large dataset of operational taxonomic units (OTUs) taken from hoofed stock samples and sum up the occurrences of OTU for each sample. For `df1`, this would generate a matrix like this:

```
 Sam1001   Sam1002
 2         1
```

Using this code:

```
require(dplyr)
dfBound <- rbind(dfSum)
dfBoundData <- as.data.frame(dfBound)
dfBoundData$X1 <- NULL
transdfBoundData <- transform(dfBoundData, dfSum = 
as.numeric(dfSum)) #although this works, it duplicates all of the rows
subttbd <- transdfBoundData[c(1, 2),]
subttbd <- subttbd[1,] 
mat.subttbd <- data.matrix(subttbd)
```

Following which I would create the graph. This works successfully for `df1`, but does not work successfully for `df2`.

**Since the issue appears to be in the creation of the list, my question is, how do I get `df2` to create a list like `df1`? Specifically, what is going on in the data frames that causes `df2` to come up with such a different (and ultimately useless when I try to manipulate it further) result?**

*Useful(?) information*

- I have not provided any replicable data because the datasets are so large, and superficially are exactly the same (as shown). If I could, I would probably be able to figure out what is going on in the "bad" one, `df2`.
- I have tried `str`, `tail`, `head` and all other combinations of tricks to determine whether there are rogue factors or characters. There *appear* to be the exact same number of integers and numerics in the dataset, and one factor (Taxon).

Comment: Can you explain what the overal goal is of the code and what the results (are supposed to) represent? I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to keep it simple but I guess it was too simple! My overall goal is to create a rarefaction of OTUs [seen here](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2015/04/16/drawing-rarefaction-curves-with-custom-colours/). I'll update the question with the next steps.

Comment: BTW, I am not following the code suggested in the link given above- just using those graphs as an example of what I'll eventually achieve through this long-winded dataset manipulation.

Comment: So effectively you are trying to create a list that says how many non-NA values there are per column?

Comment: Exactly, while maintaining the column names (unlike `df2`'s list).

Comment: does this code: `lapply(df, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))` Return the desired result for `df`? And if so does it still give the wrong result for `df2`? btw, the warning it gives, is that for `df` or `df2`?

Comment: The warning it gives if for `df2`, the problem dataset. I will get back to you on whether this code works (hopefully it does!). Interestingly, despite not having changed the data at all R is now spitting out the error `Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"` for the step `dfFreq <- apply(df, 2, count)`. So, I need to figure out what is going on there before proceeding further.

Comment: @MarijnStevering I was able to sort everything out and use your code, which worked perfectly. Thank you so much! Much smarter and shorter than the clunky method I was using, too.

Comment: Maybe show how what code you are running to make `df2`? Because clearly that's not a normal data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Marijin Stevering for the answer:

```
lapply(df, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
```

Which also neatly cuts out several steps.